# Creating NextJS app in an already initialised firebase project

Tags: firebase, next.js, firebase-hosting

I'm trying to host my website using NextJS on firebase. All the online help that I've gotten so far speaks about setting up NextJS app and then initialising Firebase project. The thing is that I have already created firebase functions for various purposes and already have a statically hosted website. I want to know how can I replace my currently hosted static website using NextJS project.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the order of operations either way, the files are independent of one another and will just need to be modified per your Next.js setup, this being SSR, SPA, Static, etc.

The key notes are to ensure you have hosting enabled inside your firebase.json file and the correct rewrites if needed.

Since you are using static generation, make sure the hosting path points to your build folder rather than the default `"public"` and if you are generating a SPA you will need to rewrite all paths to the index.html

Snippet example: firebase.json

```js
  "hosting": {
    "public": "dist/spa",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
```